# Write to Device Command Register with Pymodbus Python

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus, com-port, pymodbus3

I have a device connected to a computer's COM port. Communication with the device takes place via the modbus protocol. I need to read some information from this device - the event log. The instrument documentation is not very extensive, but it says the following:

[documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3ZUm.png)

As far as I understand, in order to initialize the log reading process, I need to write the value 1 to register 100.

Also in the documentation there is an example request:

```
[17:13:20:034] Written data (COM10)                 
    01 10 7e f4 00 01 02 00 01 ec e3    // reg. 100  // Entire log upload transfer control register, address 100 . In parameter 1.           
[17:13:20:050] Read data (COM10) 
    01 10 7e f4 00 01 58 13
```

I don't know how to understand this example correctly, so I don't know if I'm doing everything right.
My code below doesn't throw an error but doesn't produce any result. The reading process is not initialized and nothing works. What am I doing wrong? How can I correctly implement the query from the example above in python?

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient


client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port=port, stopbits=2, bytesize=8, parity='N', baudrate=19200)
client.connect()
client.write_register(address=100, value=1, unit=1)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with modbus, but as a first diagnostic step it seems like you could verify that the data being sent by your program corresponds to the example request from the documentation. It sounds like you're on Windows, so I can't offer a specific suggestion, but it looks like there are a number of serial port monitors available.

Comment: The documentation is incomplete, a write register request doesn't return any value (other than and status that indicates if there was an error or not), and given you don't get an exception, your write register request was OK, could you please share the full manual?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just had to use 'write_register**S**' instead of 'write_register'.

```
client.write_register(address=100, value=1, unit=1)
```

```
client.write_registers(address=100, value=1, unit=1)
```